# How do i fix "npm does not support Node.js v12.14.1" when they came from the same LTS download?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, gatsby, sanity

Truthfully this has never happened with me on any development environment
My node version: 12.14.1
My npm version: 6.13.4

I was building a Gatsby Site using Sanity.io as a CRM and Im getting this error:

```
ahinds$ npm run dev

> sanity-gatsby-blog@1.0.7 dev /Users/ahinds/Desktop/AHinds/dev/LMPropertyMgmt
> lerna run dev --parallel

lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info Executing command in 2 packages: "npm run dev"
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.14.1
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.14.1
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: > sanity-gatsby-blog-web@1.0.1 dev /Users/ahinds/Desktop/AHinds/dev/LMPropertyMgmt/web
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: > npm run clean-cache && gatsby develop
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: > sanity-gatsby-blog-studio@1.0.5 dev /Users/ahinds/Desktop/AHinds/dev/LMPropertyMgmt/studio
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: > sanity start
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.14.1
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: Error occured trying to resolve project root:
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 425
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! errno 1
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! sanity-gatsby-blog-studio@1.0.5 dev: `sanity start`
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! Exit status 1
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! 
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! Failed at the sanity-gatsby-blog-studio@1.0.5 dev script.
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: > sanity-gatsby-blog-web@1.0.1 clean-cache /Users/ahinds/Desktop/AHinds/dev/LMPropertyMgmt/web
sanity-gatsby-blog-web: > gatsby clean
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: npm ERR!     /Users/ahinds/.npm/_logs/2020-02-14T21_27_42_015Z-debug.log
lerna ERR! npm run dev exited 1 in 'sanity-gatsby-blog-studio'
lerna ERR! npm run dev stdout:

> sanity-gatsby-blog-studio@1.0.5 dev /Users/ahinds/Desktop/AHinds/dev/LMPropertyMgmt/studio
> sanity start


lerna ERR! npm run dev stderr:
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.14.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
Error occured trying to resolve project root:
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 425
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sanity-gatsby-blog-studio@1.0.5 dev: `sanity start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sanity-gatsby-blog-studio@1.0.5 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahinds/.npm/_logs/2020-02-14T21_27_42_015Z-debug.log

lerna ERR! npm run dev exited 1 in 'sanity-gatsby-blog-studio'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 1 child process to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sanity-gatsby-blog@1.0.7 dev: `lerna run dev --parallel`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sanity-gatsby-blog@1.0.7 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahinds/.npm/_logs/2020-02-14T21_27_42_097Z-debug.log
```

Any idea why this version of node wouldn't work with this version of npm? I installed both from the NOde.js website so they were packaged together.

Here is my [Repo](https://github.com/fullspectrumprocessing/LMPropertyMgmt)

Comment: Hi Avery can you check this error `Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 425`

Comment: @salesh okay I'll look into i don't where position 425 is though. Ill add my repo to the question.

Comment: Delete package-lock.json and node_modules, and do npm install, and try then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am pretty much sure that here is your problem

```
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: Error occured trying to resolve project root:
sanity-gatsby-blog-studio: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 425
```

Don't bother with WARNs that's alright

EDIT 1

Try to delete package-lock.json and node_modules, and do npm install, and try then

EDIT 2

After analyzing code error is in
studio -> sanity.json

[image]

I can make pull request if you want, but it's small change so go try :)

Comment: thanks you again @salesh i'll add my repo to the question, I can't seem to find where this is coming from

Comment: smh reinstalling got me 51 vulnerabilities, also i realize the project is using npm 5.10.0 but when I try to update it i get the same "npm does not support node" error"

Comment: Sorry for the lateness I was on vacation for a week. THis fix looks very promising. I'll check it out and get back on here. I appreciate your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), they should be compatible with each other.

I suggest you to uninstall npm using 'npm uninstall -g npm' and nodejs. Then reinstalling nodejs might fix the issue.